# Getting a next specific value of SQL record in PHP with looping

Tags: php, sql, oop, sorting, loops

Sorry if my english is bad. I have a table like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuV0s.jpg

What I'm trying to do is to have a function that automatically get the 6 value based from 4 value that's been embed on '$sort' variable then place it on '$bawah' variable, so I code it like this :

```
$this->nomer = $sort;
    $bawah = $this->nomer + 1;
    $cek = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM artikel_kategori WHERE sort='$bawah' LIMIT 1");
    while ($cek->num_rows() == 0) {
        $bawah = $this->bawah + 1;
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work, help me please I'm still an amateur programmer.
FYI I'm using CodeIgniter as the framework.
And what I'm trying to achieve is swapping the record of table with '$sort' value with '$bawah' value, so that the fourth row sorting position can be swapped with the fifth row. Here's my query for swapping the record :

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE artikel_kategori AS kat1 JOIN artikel_kategori AS kat2 
        ON 
            (kat1.sort='$sort' AND kat2.sort='$bawah') 
        SET 
            kat1.sort=kat2.sort, kat2.sort=kat1.sort");
```

Comment: How many tables are you dealing with?  Just one?

Comment: What criteria will allow you to select the fifth row (the value '6')?

Comment: the criteria is the next record that have higher value than the '$sort' value. For example, the $sort variable have 4 value, then the one have bigger value than 4 is 6, therefore I need to return the 6 value to $bawah variable. Here's my actual table http://i.imgur.com/yLiKR08.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, this might do the job:

```
$this->nomer = $sort;
$bawah = '';
$cek = $this->db->query("SELECT sort FROM artikel_kategori ORDER BY sort ASC");
$resArr = $cek->result_array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($resArr) - 1; $i++) {
/* for ($i = 1; $i < count($resArr); $i++) { // <-- For getting previous entry */
    $row = $resArr[$i];
    if ($row["sort"] == $sort) {
        $row2 = $resArr[$i + 1];
        /* $row2 = $resArr[$i - 1]; // <-- For getting previous entry */
        $bawah = $row2["sort"];
        break;
    }
}

if (empty($bawah)) {
    /* $sort is either the greatest/lowest value 
       or not at all present in the table */
}
```

EDIT: Fixed code according to OP's feedback (see comments).

Comment: It does work but it keeps on returning the value above it, not "6" value. Actually the sort field is not sorted like the one I explained above, but even if I added 'ORDER BY sort' on the query the result is still the same. Here's my actual table:
http://i.imgur.com/yLiKR08.jpg

Comment: Could you give some examples in form of input values for `$sort` and corresponding output values for `$bawah`. Also, are you sure you are dealing with column `sort` and not `IDKategori` (because the values you mention are from the latter) ?

Comment: For example, the $sort variable have 4 value, then the next bigger value after 4 is 6. Therefore, I need to get the 6 value to $bawah variable. Yes, I only want to deal with 'sort' column, not IDKategori because it's only for sort editing purpose without changing the other column's value. Here's my table ordered by sort to make it easier to read : http://i.imgur.com/7kbFdbi.jpg

Comment: @IkouKuhn: I updated my answer. Please, try that and if it doesn't work as expected, report the (unexpected) results (i.e. `<input> -> <output>`).

Comment: It's still the same, my expectation is if $sort -> 4 then $bawah -> 6 but from the code above, the result is like this: $sort -> 4 but $bawah -> 2 and that applies to other values, it keeps returning the same results $bawah -> 2.

Comment: I find it very weird...Let's do some debugging: For starters copy the code from **[here](http://eval.in/private/5d0ba1b87c689f)**, run it and report the results (i.e. the echoed output).

Comment: Here's the outputs: http://pastebin.com/iCRmJX1P
FYI, I fixed the typo on $ced to $cek, because if I let it be the code won't work.

Comment: @IkouKuhn: I see...Please, try out **[this one](http://eval.in/private/4beec55974a245) too. If it does work, let me know in order to update my answer. If it doesn't report the output :)'

Comment: Now it's really works!! Thanks a lot!! You really helped me! Thank you very much! Go on update it, and I'll accept it as the right answer. Just one more thing, if I want to do the opposite, for example, the $sort = 6, then I need to look the next lower value after 6, which is 4. Which part of the code should I change? I'm sorry if I ask too much, you don't have to answer this one if you don't want to. :)

Comment: I updated the answer. If you want to get the previous entry (e.g. `$sort = 6 -> $bawah = 4` you need to replace two lines (see comments inside code-block).

Comment: Thanks again! Now I'm starting to understand the flow of your code, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

it would probably be more efficient to do 1 query which returns you all 6 numbers
SELECT * FROM artikel_kategori

From there use a for loop to go through all the results and check if the result is the correct 1.

It will be much quicker to use php to loop through 6 results than to make 6 sql queries